# How get the Engine value of my server when this dont included in the django default settings

Tags: python, django, database

I am new in web programming with python, and have a problem with the connection to my database. I have already the values of name, user, pass, host, but for the connection requires too Engine value, the database don't belongs to any server predeterminates , like mysql, sqlLite, postgre etc ... i i dont know how get this value, the documentation says configure to a fully qualified path(mypackage.bakend.whaterver). 
Anyone know?
Regards

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is
>   improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings
>   documentation for more details.

Comment: so is it a db on some other server? are you using some provider to connect to your db?

Answer (score 0):

Django default configuration of database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

or if u want to connect another database(such as postgresql) u can use something like below

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'database-name',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'password-which-u-used-in-postgres',
        'HOST':'localhost'
    }
}
```

but for this u have to install postgresql.

Comment: In case of SQLserver? i already install visual c++ drivers and the Engine set  'ENGINE':'sql_server.pyodbc', and too have instaled pyodbc , but make me an error :

django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: For sql server i used 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql','Name':'Connect','PORT': '3306','USER': 'root','HOST': '127.0.0.1','PASSWORD' : '' ",

Comment: u can also follow the link [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database]